# Google Webmaster tool showing 500/502 Error on Working pages

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, google-search-console, server-error

Following Screenshots are from webmaster and my project

google webmaster
[image: Screenshot from webmaster]

my project on this link:
[image: Screenshot from getmecab]

It shows 502 error in webmaster but it is working fine. 
Same is with a lot of other URLs. I do not understand what is the reason for webmaster showing server errors for these pages suddenly when these pages were submitted long back and now they are working absolutely fine. Please tell me what could be the possible reasons for this.
I am using nginx in this project.

Comment: You shoud go to http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Ohh.. thank you... I don't know about this so I posted here.